# Attempt to index a nil value (field 'SpawnPoint)'

Tags: indexing, lua, null

I have created a fivem server for a friend of mine, and i'm currently having an issue with garages. Currently  trying to index a nil value of 'spawnpoint'

```
            for i=1, #v.Vehicles, 1 do

                if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(coords,  v.Vehicles[i].Spawner.x,  v.Vehicles[i].Spawner.y,  v.Vehicles[i].Spawner.z,  true) < Config.MarkerSize.x then
                    isInMarker     = true
                    currentStation = k
                    currentPart    = 'VehicleSpawner'
                    currentPartNum = i
                end

                if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(coords,  v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.x,  v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.y,  v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.z,  true) < Config.MarkerSize.x then
                    isInMarker     = true
                    currentStation = k
                    currentPart    = 'VehicleSpawnPoint'
                    currentPartNum = i
                end

            end
```

Comment: Well, then not every `v.Vehicles` has a `SpawnPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

As brianolive already said, it seems like not every `v.Vehicle` has a `SpawnPoint`. You can fix this for instance by proofing for existence of `SpawnPoint`.

```
if v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint and (
  GetDistanceBetweenCoords(
    coords, v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.x, v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.y,
    v.Vehicles[i].SpawnPoint.z, true
  ) < Config.MarkerSize.x
) then
```